# how to detect scrollbar on application?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, sapui5

I have an SAPUI5 app where I display a table which goes off the screen. I have a button that I the user can click to go back to the top. The problem is that button is always displayed, even when not needed. I only want it to show up when the table goes off the screen. I've been looking for solution to this but nothing has worked so far.

Here is my button defined in my xml view

```
<html: a id="toTop" href ="#_xmlview0--top">
      <Button id="backToTopBtn" text = "back"/>
</html:a>
```

and then I have this defined at the top of my view

```
<html:div id = top"></html:div>
```

I've tried different solutions I found using jquery but nothing has worked so far. I thought something like this would work

```
if($('body').height()>$(window).height()){
     //go back to top here
  }
```

but looking at these values body height and window height are the same. Any ideas?

Comment: is the table always going off the screen at the same exact location?

Comment: The table goes off after x amount of rows are displayed. The problem is that x varies based on the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

To not have your button show all the time you need to hide it using styles or javascript. I'll assume you'll use `display: none` in this case then show it when the user has scrolled a certain amount.

`element.scrollTop` and `element.scrollLeft` give you the amount of offset an element has.

If you want to show something only when the body has been scrolled a certain amount you could do:

```js
var page = document.body;
var button = document.getElementById('backToTopBtn');

function showScrollTopButton() {
    if (page.scrollTop > xyz) {
        button.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        button.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    return;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', showScrollTopButton);
```

Where `xyz` is the numerical value for when to show and hide the button.